# How can I reference and modify data of a public class which is created in a different Razor view?

Tags: html, blazor

I have a razor view I have created a public class called Model inside I have a public string called Title. How can I access this and use it in a different razor view where then I will be able to call and edit the title of it.
This is how I have created the class.

```
@code {
    public class Model
    {
        public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
    Model model = new Model();
}
```

Comment: It is better to create a base class called model outside of razor view and use it in any components you'd like, However, you can use `Cascade Parameter` to use a component parameter in all components.

Comment: Thank you very much where would I put this base class in a new CS file?

Comment: Yes. Such as my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a base class such as below in a new `.cs` file:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Now, you can use this in all component such as below:

```
<p> @myModel.Title </p>
@code{
private MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
   .
   .
   myModel.Title = "SomeString";
   .
   .
  }
}
```

Of course, it is necessary to give a reference to the namespace where the model class is inside the component.

```
@using YourProjectName.ModelFolder
```